# Syntactic function of "available" in a specific case

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In *What is the largest size available?*, what is the syntactic function of *available*? And do you know any structure similar to this one?

Thank you,

Teresa

Comment: It's an adjective and its function is **modifier** of the noun "size".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence has the noun phrase (NP)

[1] *the largest size available*

The [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of this NP is *size*. *Available* is here an adjective, functioning as an adjective phrase (AdjP). It is placed **postpositively,** so that it functions as a **post-head modifier.**

Your sentence could also be written with the adjective in attributive modifier position, i.e.

[2] *What is the largest **available** size?*

Here the NP would be

[3] *the largest available size*

The head is still *size*, and it has an attributive modifier, *available*. The nominal *available size* is then further modified by the superlative *the largest* (that's called **stacked modification**).

In [1], it is ambiguous which modifier (the pre-head one, *the largest*, or the post-head one, *available*) is applied to the head first. According to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 447),

> Examples like [iii] (*the [**gleaming** star **on the horizon**]*), with a pre-head and a post-head modifier are structurally ambiguous according to which modifier is applied to the head noun first: the immediate constituents can thus be either *gleaming star* + *on the horizon* or *gleaming* + *star on the horizon.* Usually, as in this example, it will make no practical difference whether it is taken in one way or the other.

Here is CGEL (Ch. 6, §3.3, p. 552); your example is like those in [12] i, below (note in particular the part about adjectives ending in -*able* requiring either *only* or an 'attributive superlative'; in your example, you have the latter—*the **largest** size*).

> **(c) Postpositive AdjPs**
>
> AdjPs follow the head in two kinds of NP [noun phrase] construction:
>
> [46]  i  *They want [someone **young**].*                              [compound determinative as fused head]
>            ii  *They want [a leader **younger than you**].*                                     [ordinary noun as head]
>
> In [i] the AdjP follows *someone,* which functions as fused determiner-head (cf. Ch. 5, §9.6); here there is no possibility of the AdjP occurring in attributive modifier position, and there are accordingly no structural constraints on postpositive AdjPs. In [ii] the head is an ordinary noun, so that attributive AdjPs are permitted provided they satisfy the conditions given under (b) above. For NPs that do satisfy those conditions, moreover, the attributive position is generally the default, and in many cases the only possibility [below, '*' signifies that what follows is not acceptable English]:
>
> [47]  i  a.  *They chose [a **young** leader].*        b.  **They chose [a leader **young**].*
>  
>           ii  a.  *We saw [a **black** swan].*                  b.  **We saw [a swan **black**].*
>
> Postpositive AdjPs without a post-head dependent of their own are generally restricted to the fused-head construction of [46i] or to a restricted set of adjectives, as described in Ch. 5, §14.2.

Here is the relevant section of Ch. 5,  §14.2 (pp. 445-446):

> **(b) Adjectives and AdjPs**
>
> The basic rule for the placement of adjectives and AdjPs is that single adjectives and phrases without their own post-head dependents occur in attributive position, while others occur **postpositively,** i.e. after the head of the NP, as in *members [**dissatisfied** with the board's decision].* Special rules apply with compound determinatives like *somebody, anything,* etc.: see §9.6. For the rest, there are certain specific adjectives that can or must occur postpositively. Representative examples are given in [12] (see also Ch. 6, §4.2):
>
> [12]  i  *the only day **suitable,** years **past,** proof **positive,** matters **financial,** all things **Irish***
>           ii  *the people **present,** the cars **involved,** the students **concerned,** the city **proper*** 
>          iii  *the heir **apparent,** the body **politic,** the president **elect,** the devil **incarnate,** the poet
>  
>                **laureate,** a notary **public*** 
>          iv  *the house [currently **ablaze**], all people [now **alive**], the ones **asleep***
>
> The examples in [i2i] alternate with the attributive construction: compare *the only suitable day,* etc. The postpositive use of these adjectives is subject to severe restrictions. Adjectives in *-able* or *-ible,* like *suitable* and *possible,* require an attributive superlative or *only,* compare *the best result possible* and **the result possible.* Postpositive **past** occurs with temporal nouns (cf. **approaches past*), and *positive* only with *proof.* The last two examples have general nouns as head and denote domains; the adjectives *financial* and *Irish* are like restrictors (§9.6) in that they must immediately follow the head.
>
> The adjectives in [12ii] occur both attributively and postpositively, but with a difference in sense. Postpositive *present* (or *absent*) denotes a temporary state of affairs: compare *the present government.* The same applies to *involved* and *concerned,* though here the attributive sense differs more (cf. *deeply involved activists, concerned parents*). Postpositive *proper* means "in the strict/proper sense of the term". With *net* and *gross* the choice of position depends not on the meaning but on the head: they follow specific sums (*fifty dollars net*) but otherwise precede (*my net income*).
>
> The examples in [12iii] are fixed phrases, with no attributive alternant. The adjectives in [iv] are ones which are altogether excluded from attributive position.